# How to set SSH identify file path

Tags: gitahead

I'm trying to push some code to my company internal Git repository via SSH, but I kept getting the following error:

> Unable to push to ssh://git@serveradddress:1234/wpk/repotest.git -
> failed to find SSH identify file

How can I set the path to my SSH identify file in GitAhead?

Comment: Does git push work on the command line?

Comment: Yes, push from Git bash client works.

Comment: That means you are on Windows, correct? I can't help you any further then, assuming that problem is platform specific.

Answer (score 1):

For me I placed the IP / exmple.com in front of 'Host' and removed HostName, that fixed it for me.

As for setting the config or ssh key location, both options can be found in tools->options->misc.